# finding the radius of a found circle opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

```
cv::Mat circles;
std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circlesVEC;
cv::cvtColor(quad,circles,CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::HoughCircles(circles,circlesVEC,CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10 ,100, 30, 1, 30);
```

this part of code find all circles found in the Mat circles my question how do I know how big is the radius of each found circle  ? 
 thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circles stored in matrix one circle per row, and columns are x,y,r , so for get circle info you can use the code below:

```
 cv::Point Center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
 int Radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
```